# Approx. what fraction of viruses will manipulate the installed antivirus program to make themselves undetected once they are in RAM?

Tags: virus, anti-virus, malware

If this percentage is high, why do people still bother to run AV after the PC is booted; why is it not the norm to boot from media (disc etc.) and then scan the infected disk (when there is no chance that the virus can go into RAM)?

Comment: Because once a signature is developed the malware cannot hide.  One must remember that the physical process still exists, even if the malware, attempts to hide itself.  Furthermore has Scandalist points out, the criminals that write the Malware, write it in a way that unless its running detection is unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many pieces of malware hook themselves into drivers and other system processes that are not loaded when booting from live media or safe mode.

I tested this on a heavily infected machine, both with malware bytes and combofix. I did both a scan in safe mode and took the drive out to scan the slave.

Nothing was detected until I booted back in to the operating system and scanned during normal operation.

Comment: did you mean to write loaded instead of 'not loaded' in your first sentence? in any case what type of driver would be loaded when you scan the drive as a slave?

Comment: No, when you boot from live media or slave a drive you're dealing only with the disk and whatever files are on the file system. There are no drivers loaded either, just static data.

Comment: In that case I am confused by the last sentence: "Nothing was detected until I booted back in to the operating system and scanned during normal operation." Why would you not find anything UNTIL you load the OS and the malware goes into RAM? Further, the question is about the frequency of viruses that have this behavior and best practices. Thanks for the anecdote anyway.

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn - It was because the malware was in memory, because of a detected signature, that it was able to be identified.  We can't answer your actual question, we cannot tell you the percentage of malware that does this, because there are hundreds of new signatures daily that are created.  Besides the actual number doesn't matter, the majority of infections are found because of signature based detection not behavioral detection ( altough the difference between the two make doing both important ).

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks, I get it now. What makes a signature invisible on disk and visible in memory? EDIT: Nevermind: Just saw your main comment.

Comment: @Ramhound: Even though new viruses are detected every day, we can study the properties of the existing pool. This is useful to know since when the user suspects infection, he knows what to do in the average case.

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn = Why not leave research malware to the professionals, the people who write the signatures and reverse engineer malware, and concentrate on making the systems you use as secure as possible by understanding what attack vectors are used the most.  **I should add it actually is normal to do a malware scan before entering the operating system.**

Comment: @Ramhound: I'll continue to claim that knowing the stats is useful to the layman. If I suspect malware and can't detect it on disk and also not in RAM, it would be useful to know whether the effort of reformat is worth it. If the estimated fraction that evades both types of scans is close to 0, I wouldn't bother to reformat and assume that the virus-like symptoms are caused by something else.

Comment: We cannot estimate the percentage there are millions of different and unique malicious files with each of hundreds of different variations of their signature.  Most malware try to evade detection in some way